# Debugging Eclipse Application Problem: Launches repeatedly

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I'm having a problem debugging an Eclipse Application from Eclipse.  When I launch the Debug Configuration, the Eclipse Application starts up and then stops repeatedly.  It shows the splash screen and then disappears.  This is the farthest it gets before restarting:

```
MyDebugConfiguration [Eclipse Application]  
    org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main at localhost:2599 
        Thread [main] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [Signal Dispatcher] (Running) 
        Daemon Thread [State Data Manager] (Running)    
        Daemon Thread [Framework Event Dispatcher] (Running)    
        Thread [State Saver] (Running)  
        Daemon Thread [Start Level Event Dispatcher] (Running)  
        Thread [Refresh Packages] (Running) 
    C:\MyApp\eclipse\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe (Sep 18, 2008 9:38:19 AM)
```

I am using Version 3.4.0 of the Eclipse SDK.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried launching Eclipse with the -clean option? This may resolve the issue if it's somehow related to a configuration problem or the registry cache.

Answer (score 0):

Does your eclipse application have an analog to the hidden logfile in the workspace on launch of the IDE?  You can find this in workspace/.metadata/.log

If your application has that somewhere, you might be able to get a little bit better information on what's happening at startup of your eclipse app.

Answer (score 0):

I always add the `-console` and `-consoleLog` to the launch configuration.

The first will dump the eclipse log to the console, and the second gives you access to the [OSGi console](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-ecl-osgiconsole/index.html).

In this situation, I check the status of all bundles (using `ss`). Chances are that the bundle you are interested in hasn't been started. This is probably due to:

- an exception in the Activator.
- an unresolved dependency of the bundle.

If you haven't already seen the error via the consoleLog, then you try and start the bundle manually on the console, with `start <bundle-number>`. The `<bundle-number>` is the index of the bundle as seen in `ss` output. If it is a problem starting the bundle, then the stack trace will be useful in tracking down the real problem.